# Smooth text scrolling in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I started known about FLASG a few day ago. I am very, very interesting about its.
My boss want i make a text display in bottom screen and scrolling from right to left (same as display on TV).
But, i used to keyframe to solved this solution but they are slowly and not smooth. Now i want text display running smoother.
I not good at Flash .I am programmer , C# is my programming language.

Can you give me an example or helpful tutorial, please.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean like captions/subtitles?

Answer (score 0):

In Flash, Suuport a Basic Animation Class. But many programmer not used it.
Because there is a awesome framework. that is TweenMax, gTween...

Refer to the following sites will be a lot of help to you.

http://www.greensock.com -> Very Awesome Animation Framework. Very Easy.

http://www.activeden.net -> Many Useful Tutorial. Very Famous Site...

Answer (score 0):

In the "Properties" panel for the textfield, you want to change the Anti-alias mode of the text from "Anti-alias for readability" to "Anti-alias for animation". This should make it smooth and scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If the text isn't dynamic, select it, right click it and select break apart a couple times - until it's converted to vector.

Scrolling text likes to try snap to the nearest pixel, so converting to vector should fix this.

[image]